# Cloning specific directories with file extensions in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, file, build, dockerfile, containers

I am building a Docker image where I need to clone specific directories from the current working directory on the host machine into the Docker container while preserving the original directory structure. I want to achieve this using a Dockerfile. As an example lets say that I am only interested in moving directories that contain Java files (`*.java`) along with their contents. I want to achieve this using a Dockerfile.

Here is an example scenario to clarify the requirement:
Let's say my current working directory on the host machine is as follows:

```
./
├── folder1
│   ├── file1.txt
│   └── file2.doc
├── folder2
│   ├── file3.java
│   └── file4.py
└── folder3
    ├── file5.xml
    └── file6.java
```

In this case, I am interested in cloning the following directories and their contents to the Docker container:

```
/app
├── folder2
│   ├── file3.java
│   └── file4.py
└── folder3
    ├── file5.xml
    └── file6.java
```

Here is the relevant part of my Dockerfile:

```
FROM <base_image>

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Clone specific directories with Java files from the host machine
# [Need guidance on the Dockerfile command]

# Other Dockerfile instructions...
```

What should be the appropriate Dockerfile command or set of commands to clone the directories (`folder2` and `folder3`) and their contents from the current working directory on the host machine while preserving the original structure? I would greatly appreciate any suggestions or examples.

Note: I want to achieve this using Dockerfile commands without relying on external scripts or manual intervention.

Comment: You could copy the whole thing and then run this find command RUN find /temp -type f -name '*.java' -exec sh -c 'cp --parents "{}" /app/

Comment: Hi thanks for your input but it gives an error `#10 0.314 /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Comment: oh yeah I missed a single quote try adding that